# Hibernate querying every item of a Collection before inserting it's parent. Why?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have an entity `A` that has a Set of `B` entities.

It's a bidirectional relationship. In `A` it's mapped with `@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy=...)`.

I'm trying to do a `.save()` on a newly constructed `A` full of newly constructed `Bs`.

First, Hibernate query every single `B` in the collection to "get it's current state". Then, it inserts `A`, then it inserts `Bs`, one by one.

Why not start checking that `A` doesn't exist and then inserting everything?

**UPDATE**

If I change `.save()` for `.persist()` it works as I expected: only inserts, no queries.

Comment: Either they're supposing that the Bs can exists independently from A, or maybe it could be a 'feature'